# Good style to call advanced constructor from unparametrized constructor?

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style

I was just discussing with some colleagues about Java constructors, design-patterns and good way to initialize objects with a unparametrized constructor if I normally await some parameters.

One of the older ones came up with his way of implementing always something like:

```
public class Foo {

public Foo() {
this(0,0,0);
}

public Foo(int a, int b, int c) {
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
this.c = c;
}
..
}
```

My question is, is that good style and what is its behaviour exactly?

From what I understand should be:

- it instantiates first an Object and then calling the parametrized constructor to construct a new object of that type with that parameter settings and set its own reference to the new one. So the GC has then to delete the first created one.

Comment: It's not the constructor who instantiates an object, it's the `new` keyword. The constructor is only responsible for initialising the object.

Comment: so it's always the new keyword that allocates the memory and the constructors are just the charging of the object? (also for c++?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
So the GC has then to delete the first created one.
```

No. Only 1 instance is ever created when chaining constructors.

To answer your question, yes, it's good style, assuming you need both `foo()` and `foo(int, int, int)`

Answer (score 6):

This is known as [Telescoping Constructor pattern](http://theyjustdidit.com/telescopic-constructor-pattern/). In Effective Java, Joshua provides [alternatives](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/EffectiveJava.aspx) with suggestions on which one to use when.